# Как кастомизировать dispatchTouchEvent?

Tags: android

У меня есть общий Activity в нем я слушаю dispatchTouchEvent. Если какое то нажатие по экрану произошло то происходит одно действие.

Но тут мне пришлось добавить некую VIew , после я добавил ее поверх основного Layout.

И теперь мне надо как - то этот View ОГРАДИТЬ от dispatchTouchEvent. Тобишь если нажимаем на экране на все кроме данного View то срабатывает dispatchTouchEvent.

Если нажимаем на View то dispatchTouchEvent не должен работать.

Как это реализовать в ANdroid? и реализуется ли такое ввобще?

---

Для каждого View OnClick прописывать не получится. У меня их там порядка 30.

А еще такие окон штук 10

---

Исходники

```
   @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean isDispatch = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (!mTouchForOutcast) {

            }else {
                videoControllerView.setVisibleViewController(true);
                subTitleView.setMarginMoveBottom(false);
            }
        }

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (timerVisiblePlayer != null) {
                timerVisiblePlayer.cancel();
                timerVisiblePlayer = null;
            }
        }

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mTouchForOutcast = false;
            if (timerVisiblePlayer != null) {
                timerVisiblePlayer.cancel();
                timerVisiblePlayer = null;
            }
            timerVisiblePlayer = new Timer();

            timerVisiblePlayer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            videoControllerView.setVisibleViewController(false);
                            subTitleView.setMarginMoveBottom(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        return isDispatch;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с того, что внутри `Activity` метод `dispatchTouchEvent` должен срабатывать всегда, а потому лучше немного изменить поставленную задачу. Например проверить, является ли касание событием для "отверженной" `View`, и если нет, тогда выполнить действие. Покажу на примере:

Вынесем в поле класса `boolean` переменную:

```
private boolean mTouchForOutcast;
```

В `Activity` найдём Вашу "отверженную" `View` и установим ей следующий `Listener`:

```
findViewById(R.id.outcast_view).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mTouchForOutcast = true;  
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

А внутри метода `dispatchTouchEvent` у `Activity` передаём событие по иерархии, а потом проверяем, поймала ли его Ваша "отверженная" `View`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction();
    boolean isDispatch = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    if (!mTouchForOutcast) {
        // тут Ваш код
    }
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        mTouchForOutcast = false;            
    }
    return isDispatch;
}
```

**UPD**: Немного оптимизировал Ваш код (`Timer` был явно неуместен), теперь примерно так должно выглядеть:

```
private static final long DELAY = 5000;

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        videoControllerView.setVisibleViewController(false);
        subTitleView.setMarginMoveBottom(true);
    }
};

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction();
    boolean isDispatch = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    if (!mTouchForOutcast) {
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            videoControllerView.setVisibleViewController(true);
            subTitleView.setMarginMoveBottom(false);
        }
    }
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            videoControllerView.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            videoControllerView.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
            mTouchForOutcast = false;
            break;
    }
    return isDispatch;
}
```

Comment: Вообще задачи Вашей я не знаю, но всматриваясь в код, мне показалось, что логика происходящего должна быть такой. Еще раз изменил код, попробуйте, мб Вам подойдёт :) Если таких особых View две штуки, то слушатель на обе надо будет повешать.

Comment: Добавил работает вроде. 

А что вы изменилили?

Comment: Кстати можете обхяснить в чем смысл вашгего кода. Работать работает но я не понял что - то. допустим зачем 

`boolean isDispatch = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);`

И как именно работает логика вашего кода

Comment: Изменения в логике сделал такое - при нажатии на вашу особую кнопку  происходит removeCallbacks, чтобы под пальцем пользователя ничего не пропало, пока он его не отпустит :) А super.dispatchTouchEvent передаёт событие касания далее по иерархии всем элементам, по логике вещей без super.dispatchTouchEvent ни одна кнопка у Вас не сможет нажаться, потому что событие им не придёт.

Comment: Можете дать мне ссылку неа статью или видеоурок по этой штуке. А то я щяс использую ваш код. А в будущем не смогу реализовать его .

Comment: Да вроде как я только из описаний к методу принцип действия dispatchTouchEvent понял + посмотрел остальные методы связанные с touch, с помощью студии можно методы фильтровать по слову Touch и читать к ним описания. Но думаю можно погуглить "обработка касаний", чтобы найти статьи :)

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо вам)